# programming in online judge like spoj ,topcoder

Tags: c++, c

i am new to programming.but i want to do programming? i want to ask that how to interpret the question in spoj or other online judge ? i have stated reading different algorithms and books based on that but unable to solve any problem please guide me .please
i am using c language.

most of the question in spoj and other online judge uses dynamic programming approach but after reading whole dynamic programming i am not able to figure out the problem stated or not able to start.please help

Comment: Please reformulate your question to actually be a question - we cannot help otherwise.

Comment: Have you written the "Hello world" program already? Start with that, long **long** before doing dynamic programming.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of the problems at the [UVa Online Judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/)?

There's a good companion book called [Programming Challenges](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387001638) that shows how to submit code to the judge and outlines over 100 of the problems in 14 different categories (DP is only one of them).